# is it considerably faster to query different tables than having a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

imagine that we have this table:

```
create table Foo(
id int,
name varchar,
k int --can be 1 or 2 or 3
)
```

or we could have 3 tables for each value of k

```
create Fook1(
id int,
name varchar
)
...
create table Fook2
...
createa table Fook3
```

is it going to be considerably faster to do:

```
select * from Foo where k = 3
```

than doing:

```
select * from Fook3
```

Comment: Can you give a **real** example?  If you only have 3 values, it will be (theoretically) faster to have them in separate tables

Comment: For any number it will probably be faster. The question is whether or not it will be worth the tradeoff, which will be determined by how it can be indexed, how many extra tables and logical hoops need to be jumped through as that number gets larger from 3, how much extra maintenance is required for N number of tables, etc. With proper indexing and the possibility of partitioning, this design pattern should be mostly extinct though.

Comment: @JNK: Only if OP only request for FOOK with a unique value of `k`. If not, it would take 2 queries + an union, which would be slower than # query with a `WHERE`

Comment: What indexes have been defined? For example, if there is an index on column "k", performance would be nearly same in either solution. Query will scan index pages to figure out which queries to include in result and hit actual data pages only for those rows. In extreme case, you can even create an index that is sorted on K and has all columns you need in select.

Comment: @ShamitVerma you can define everything you want, any indexes and stuff

Comment: Then with a "proper" index, performance would be exactly same. In DB2/Sybase/MS SQL, this would be a "clustered" index that would keep table sorted on column "K". Query would start reading from the page that has data that is needed and end on the page where value of K changes. But choice of index would also depend on type and rate of changes.

Comment: @Sharmit Verma the k is not going to change at all, that's why I was able to consider different tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***-Do-Not-Do-That-***

Oh, wait, that's not helpful, it's just beligerant :)

Partitioning the data in this way CAN yield performance benefits.  But they also introduce other costs:
- Queries that need to span all three tables become more complex
- Your schema becomes more cluttered
- It's easier to make mistakes
- It's hard to ensure referential integrity
- You may need to include a view to unify the 3 tables

You are most likely much better off with an Index that has `k` within it.  And depending on how you query the data, `k` may be the first field in that index.  When you specify `k = ?`, it just needs to do a Very quick check in the index and then you're only looking at the relevant portion of the table.  And, if the index is a `clustered` index, the data is even physically stored in that order.

I'd highly recommend making use of indexes in this way before partitioning your data.  It's an optimisation with costs, and so should be approached when it can be shown Necessary, not as a safety net early in design.

Comment: so if k has a clustered index, it's the same ?

Comment: If there is a clustered index, with k as the first field in the index, the data will be physically sorted with k=1 first, k=2 next, and so on.  When querying `WHERE k=2`, the first step is to lookup the range that k=2 covers, a very very fast step indeed.

Answer (score 5):

Potentially, using multiple tables *could* be faster than using a single table (particularly if those tables are going to have many millions of records), but there would be trade-offs in terms of ease of use, manageability, etc.

However, you could have the benefits of both by [partitioning your table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Partioning is the answer here, it hides the complexity.

Comment: I agree that partitioning is the answer. I just wanted to put in a vote for using TABLE INHERITANCE if your DB supports it, which can also hide the physical implementation and keep this decision relatively transparent to end users.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on the DB, so a real example is needed. For instance, in Oracle you can use partitioning, which does exactly what you say here behind the curtains, or create a materialized view with the union and then have the option to do both. 
Normally, I'd say that you should create a correct implementation and then tune; early optimization is the root of all evils, especially with DBs. I think it is quite likely that your bottleneck is not going to be where you expect it.